# sharedpreferences remains when the app is closed

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, lifecycle

I'm saving some data into sharedpreferences and my problem is the data remains even when the App is closed, and even if the pda is reset

Another question about the lifecycle, my App should keep working in background and it does if i press the "menú" button of my pda, choose other apps in the meanwhile, etc... But if I press the "back" button, it executes the ondestroy method and the App doesn't keep working.

Thanks!

Comment: What did you expect from SharedPreferences? Also, if you want a different behaviour from you Back menu, you have to override the onBackPressed method...

Comment: I tried to override the onbackpressed method, the problem is now the App does nothing when i press the backbutton. How could i make it behave like the menú button?

Comment: Odd, very odd... but I will tell you. You can call `openOptionsMenu();`, so to open the menu programmatically.

Comment: yes it is odd, xD. I tried the service option at the end and now it Works fine. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sharedpreferences are designed to do just that. persist data between app executions..

-- http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

if you want your app to remain active in the background you need to have it run as a service.

-- https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html

Comment: but I need the ActivityManager and Package manager, and also put the results in the interface. Can I do it from a Service?

Comment: what do you mean by "put the results in the interface?"  you can store the results of a piece of code in shared preferences, local files, a database, or a ton of other options..

Comment: Thank you very much. In the end I did the service and works great

Answer (score 0):

The sharedpreferences are intented to stay when the app is closed. It's just an xml-file storing your data. If you don't need some of the values you either may reset them in the onCreate of your Base-Activity or define a global class that extends Application and store your data there in global variables.